# pm2 safe way to use max_memory_restart

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I'm building a Node.js + Express web application using pm2 cluster mode as a load balancer. This turned out to be a big performance improvement, as my application now spawns an instance of itself for each one of my CPU cores.

To make the most advantage of it, i'm using a custom start script-- in which I added pm2's **max_memory_restart** option, so if one of the instances exceed 400mb memory usage it restarts itself. Seeing that behavior in action, I couldn't avoid myself to question **if it is safe to use this option**. Although it's nice to have an auto-restart kick in when memory grows over certain point, I thought of two possible downsides:

- If one of my endpoints has memory intensive usage, said instance could restart itself in the middle of processing giving the user an error
- If my server has, let's say, 2GB of RAM and 8 CPU cores, then the max_memory_restart option should be max 256mb if I'm running pm2 in cluster mode, as it applies for each instance. Isn't there any risk giving a fairly low max_memory_restart value here? Theoretically the instances would be restarting frequently in this case

Given these scenarios, **Is it safe/adequate to use pm2's max_memory_restart option?**

Comment: Hi, while using this sometimes CPU utilization goes higher only for some instances, then it freezes it doesnt take up the incoming requests. After restarting it comes back to normal. Will the max_memory_restart work for CPU utilization goes high. Could you please let me know?

Comment: I am also at an impasse pondering how to do the memory restart safely! Did you find any reliable way to do this? Thanks. @Sergio Palmeiras